# How can i add active class on new tab

Tags: meteor

When i click browser back button then nav bar menus was not active.
I solved it as below code inside onRendered function.

```
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var Rname = Router.current().route.getName();
    if(Rname == 'xxx'){
        $('.lib').addClass('active');
        $('.default').removeClass('active');
        $('.OnBack').removeClass('active');
    }
    if(Rname == 'yyy'){
        $('.lib').removeClass('active');
        $('.default').addClass('active');
        $('OnBack').removeClass('active');
    }
    if(Rname == 'zzz'){
        $('.lib').removeClass('active');
        $('.default').removeClass('active');
        $('.OnBack').addClass('active');
    }
});
```

But when i copy URL and open in new tab then `Rname` gives correct value but active class not add.
How can i solve it.
Please Rply soon....

I want that if condition code execute using another function, because i have many conditions. How can be solve it in meteor???

Comment: I think it's probably better to put the code in the ```onRendered()``` of the navbar templatee rather than the router's ```onRendered```. That way, each time the navbar template gets rendered, those classes get attached / removed.

Comment: i am just beginner. i am not understand about router's onRendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [zimme:active-route](https://atmospherejs.com/zimme/active-route). It does exactly what you need. Just read the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! it's nice.